# QGIS split HTML code table into different fields

Tags: qgis, html

I'm using QGIS. I have a KMZ file, which I have converted to a GPKG layer, with a column containing HTML code. That HTML encodes additional fields as lines in a table.

I would like to extract those additional fields into new columns in my gpkg table.

Here is an example of the html-coded table:

```
<html><body><table border="1"><tr><th>Field Name</th><th>Field Value</th></tr><tr><td>GlobalID</td><td>{D7537371-0A42-4DC7-A7F9-432FC741DF7F}</td></tr><tr><td>CreationDate</td><td>10/18/2020 9:26:10 AM</td></tr><tr><td>Creator</td><td>sfares</td></tr><tr><td>EditDate</td><td>3/20/2021 11:29:41 AM</td></tr><tr><td>Editor</td><td>sfares</td></tr><tr><td>Archaeo Site</td><td>Null</td></tr><tr><td>Other - Type</td><td>Null</td></tr><tr><td>Isolated artefact</td><td>other</td></tr><tr><td>Other - Isolated artefact</td><td>stone tool</td></tr><tr><td>Observations</td><td>Null</td></tr><tr><td>Site Extension</td><td>Null</td></tr><tr><td>Site Name</td><td>WS20-AGC</td></tr><tr><td>ID Number</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>Nbr of pieces</td><td>Null</td></tr><tr><td>Latitude</td><td>Null</td></tr><tr><td>Longitude</td><td>Null</td></tr><tr><td>Altitude</td><td>Null</td></tr><tr><td>Haccuracy</td><td>Null</td></tr><tr><td>Vaccuracy</td><td>Null</td></tr><tr><td>Satellites</td><td>Null</td></tr><tr><td>Position Source </td><td>Null</td></tr><tr><td>Altitude Type</td><td>Null</td></tr><tr><td>Ecosite Type</td><td>Null</td></tr><tr><td>Ecosite Extension</td><td>Null</td></tr><tr><td>X UTM38N</td><td>Null</td></tr><tr><td>Y UTM38N</td><td>Null</td></tr><tr><td>Point Type</td><td>feature</td></tr><tr><td>Previous ID</td><td>Null</td></tr></table></body></html>
```

Comment: Have you tried the plugin "KML Tools" it has a function named "Expand HTML description field" to extract the KML/KMZ description to individual columns.  It doesn't always work - depends if the layout of your description matches one of the plugins predefined formats.  Worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

A robust solution that fully parses any syntactically valid HTML table, extracting whatever field names are within it, will probably require writing a **Python script which uses an XML converter** like `lxml`. Then you could extract the fields therein as a dictionary or array, and then add those elements as fields to your layer. This is doable but will take some effort unless someone's already built a plug-in that does it.

However, **if you know what the field names in the table are, and you can be sure the way the table is encoded** is precisely as in your example, you can do the following.

1. Load up the layer with the HTML table as a string field. I'll assume it's called `"HTML Table"`; modify below accordingly.
2. For each field you want to extract, in QGIS use **Field Calculator** to create it (potentially even as a virtual field).
3. While creating it, populate it with a field expression that uses **regex** to extract the relevant item in the table.

For this field expression, the following works for me with the table HTML exactly as you specified, replacing `GlobalID` with the right field name for each field:

`try(regexp_substr("HTML Table",'GlobalID'||'</td><td>(.+?)</td>'),NULL)`

As explanation, and in case you or a future reader needs to modify this for their situation:

- The `'GlobalID'||'gobbledygook'` is regex syntax that looks for a table cell containing precisely `GlobalID`, the field name, in one table cell, and then grabs the contents of the next cell over, which is (hopefully) the intended value of that field. `.+` means one or more characters. The rest looks for it preceded by the field name and `</td><td>` and due to the `?` (indicating lazy in regex) it matches as few characters as possible up the first possible next `</td>`. Finally, the `()` means it only returns that group, not the delimiters around it.
- `regexp_substr` is a QGIS field expression function that applies that regex pattern and pulls out the substring it matches, which is what you want
- the `try(...)` wrapper makes sure you get a null value back if the field can't be found or there's some sort of syntax error. It may not be necessary (maybe `regexp_susbtr` always fails elegantly) but I like using it with arcane or fragile stuff to avoid inscrutable errors for users if anything goes wrong, something I didn't test for when coding it.